# Using Click's clear function

Tags: python, libraries

I am making a project in Python that requires the shell window to be cleared at a certain point. I have tried several methods of clearing the shell, none of which have worked for me. I asked a few programming friends of mine, and they told me to use the Click library.

My clear function calls this:

```
click.clear()
```

However, when I run this in the shell, nothing happens at all. There's no error message, but there is no effect either. I am using Python 3.5.1. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the full code:

```
# Word Game
import random
import time
import click
def clearshell():
  click.clear()
loopy = True
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 
's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
random.shuffle(alphabet)
b = alphabet[0:16]
answers = []
game = True
while game == True:
  print(' Use the letters in the grid to form a word.\n You are allowed to repeat letters (ex. 
  \'letter\')')
  print(' The letters do NOT have to be connected. You may use any letters in the box together.')
  print(' If you repeat a word that another player has entered, you\'ll be eliminated.')
  print('   ')
  print('', b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], '\n', b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7], '\n', b[8], b[9], b[10], b[11], 
  '\n', b[12], b[13], b[14], b[15])
  print('   ')
  answer = input(' Word? ')
  if answer.lower() in answers:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    game = False
  else:
    answers.append(answer.lower())
  clearshell()
print('You have been eliminated!')
print('List of words:')
for x in range(len(answers)):
  print(answers[x])  
for x in range(3):
  print('   ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace with this function. I have used `system` method from `os` module to do it:

```py
from os import system
def clearshell():
    system('cls') #for windows
    #system('clear') <-- for linux/macOS
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and it didn't seem to work. You're certain that this clears the Python shell?

Comment: @Edmond301 I cannot post any answer without being certain about the expected results and also I never post any answer without testing it on my environment.